# Trouble binding a WPF DataGrid to a DataView with column names that are invalid as a property path

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, escaping, propertypath

Given the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataViewBindingTrouble.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" x:Name="Win">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Win, Path=TestData}" 
AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" />
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DataViewBindingTrouble
{
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataView TestData
    {
        get
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var newRow = dt.NewRow();
            var newCol = dt.Columns.Add();
            //newCol.ColumnName = "uniqueColName";
            var troublemaker = "This is not a [valid] property path and causes.trouble]";
            //newCol.Caption = troublemaker;
            newCol.ColumnName = troublemaker;
            newRow[newCol] = "Foobar";
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            return dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }

    private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
       // e.Column.Header = TestData.Table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
       //     .Single(someCol => someCol.ColumnName == e.PropertyName).Caption;
    }
}
}
```

The auto generator for columns produces a binding with an invalid property path because the special characters contained in the column name are not escaped.
I can circumvent this without too much trouble by using the commented out code (read: add harmless column names and keep the caption seperately), but in case I have no control over my data source, how would one handle this? I thought about using a PropertyDescriptor instead of a simple property path, but failed to find an easy way how to get PropertyDescriptors for a DataTable's columns without writing a custom wrapper.

Are there any obvious options I did miss?

Comment: The most obvious thing to do would be to fix your binding paths/column names in my opinion.

Comment: The column names are defined by users. The first case where this problem was noticed was someone who had a column titled "Time [min]" which is perfectly ok for me. This led only to an empty field (because the expression was ok, but looking for something that was not there). If you have any characters after the closing ], you already get an exception while creating the binding. And who am I to tell the user which characters/orders of characters he has to avoid when naming his columns?

Comment: @PatrickKursawe Where do users define the column names, directly in the DB or in your UI somewhere? If the latter, you can transform them into something less obnoxious for the DataTable, and use the user's name as a "display name" in the column header.

Comment: Well, I already implemented a similar workaround in the commented lines, but I just wondered how to deal best with a situation where this would be no option - hence the question.